# Зачем нужен класс DB?

Tags: c#, sql

Меня учили что нужно использовать при работе с БД вот такой класс:

```
class DB
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Строка подключения");
    public void OpenConnection()
    {
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();
    }
    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
    }
    public SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return con;
    }
    public string ReturnFromDB(string s)
    {
        OpenConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(s, GetConnection());
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        string x = "";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            x = reader[0].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close(); CloseConnection();
        return x;
    }
}
```

Вот так:

```
        DB db = new DB();
        db.OpenConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Команда", db.GetConnection());
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            data.Add(new string[1]);
            data[data.Count - 1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
        db.CloseConnection();
```

Зачем он нужен если можно и без этого класса обойтись?

```
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Команда";
            NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                data.Add(new string[1]);
                data[data.Count - 1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
            }
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
```

Спрашивал у преподавателя, но нормального ответа не получил...

Можно ли как то код сократить?

Comment: это плохой класс, не используй его. Но и без класса код плохой

Comment: `Можно ли как то код сократить?` можно научиться работать с ORM, например Entity Framework, и забыть про ADO.NET как про страшный сон.

Answer (score -2):

Сократить можно. Но не нужно.

Принцип единственной ответственности (буква S из SOLID). если это у тебя контроллер - он должен только получить результат из сервиса бизнес-логики и отдать его в нужном виде.

Если это сервис бизнес-логики - он не должен получать данные из базы, он должен получать их из класса-репозитория. Dependency inversion (буква D из SOLID) - реализация должна зависеть от абстракций. Неважно, откуда будут получены данные, важно то, что метод `ReturnFromDb` отдал строку.

Если у нас это всё завязано на класс (по хорошему, конечно, на интерфейс) `DB` - то мы можем спокойно сменить базу данных с MySql на Postgres, или вообще вынести получение данных во внешний сервис - и наш код, который использует данные из базы, никак не поменяется если не поменялся контракт.

Если мы всё - и чтение данных, и их обработку, и возврат результата потребителю -  впихнём в один класс - это будет ужасный, страшный франкенштейн, с очень сильной связностью, который будет сложно поддерживать и сложно тестировать.

Comment: Где ты вообще видишь в коде вызов `ReturnFromDB`? А если бы он даже был, ты его код видел? В него передаётся строка sql-запроса, а метод читает все получившиеся строки результата и среди них возвращает первую колонку последней строки. Т. е. вызывающий код ответственен за формирование запроса и порядок колонок, но сам не умеет добавлять desc к сортировке и top 1 к select'у - какое-то хреновое разделение ответственности. К тому же, за счёт чтения кучи строк вместо одной ещё и производительность убивает.